# Quick Help missing full Description

Tags: swift, xcode

Updated Xcode to 11.6. When I control-click to view Quick Help all I get is the declaration. I've searched forum and uninstalled Xcode completely, deleted all items in ~/Library/Developer, emptied the trash, restarted the computer, and then reinstalled Xcode from App Store.

The window shows Declaration and Parameters but Description is missing. Is this something new with Xcode 11.6?

Comment: Control-click does not do Quick Help. You want Option-click. — So, can you give an example? What term are you getting Quick Help for? Try to give instructions one can reproduce. Xcode 11.6 works fine for me.

Comment: Sorry, I meant Option-Click. Here is a screenshot of a page from Apple's new book along with my Option-Click popup which does NOT match what the text says I should be seeing./Users/krgraham/Desktop/Screen Shot 2020-07-21 at 10.09.24 PM.pdf

Comment: Sorry, I meant Option-Click. In the latest Apple book "Develop in Swift Extensions" it shows an example of Quick Help for .hasPrefix text with a Description, but when I try to reproduce this on code I only get Declaration and Parameters without any Description as per the example in the book.

Answer (score 1):

Works fine for me. Screen shot shows that this is Xcode 11.6 and we are seeing plenty of Description (actually it's called Discussion).

[image]